# Building reusable UI compontents in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

[INFO] iPhone Device family: iphone
    [INFO] iPhone SDK version: 5.0
    [INFO] Projekt/1.0 (2.0.2.GA.2ff31a3)

I am building an iOS app in Appcelerator and in this app I want to create a CommonJS module for UI components that I add to the global variable and then use it in other commonJS modules.

My code is based upon this example:

```
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/09/forging-titanium-episode-6-a-single-context-tabbed-application-template.html
```

I add it into app.js like this:

```
var globals = {};

globals.Components = require ('ui/Components');
```

I use it in other modules like this:

```
var button_right = new globals.Components.NavBarButton ();
```

Is this a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium#CommonJSModulesinTitanium-GlobalVariables):

> There shall not be ANY global variables in a Titanium application shared across all modules. **Any data a module or any objects exposed by a module require should be passed in during construction or initialization.**

So, you preferably pass any other parameter on new object's initialization, something like:

```
var module = new Module(param);
```